# MPI_Allreduce uses different cpu time at different solver location

Tags: mpi

In the solver, I implements MPI to do simulation. I use clock() to check the CPU time of each part of the solver. The following code is used to check the CPU time:

```
MPI_Barrier(SlaveComm);
clock_t pre_dot1 = clock();
newrho = symmat->Lddot_MPI(n,r,z,false); 
clock_t after_dot1 = clock();
time_dot3 += (after_dot1 - pre_dot1)/(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Lddot_MPI is a very simple function which calculates the dot as shown by the following code:

```
double BaseMatrix::Lddot_MPI(int n,double x[], double y[], bool forall){
// the dot product of two vectors.

double dsum(0.0);

for (int ii=0; ii<n; ii++)
{
    dsum = dsum + x[ii]*y[ii];
}

double dsum_total(0.0);

if (forall)
    MPI_Allreduce(&dsum, &dsum_total, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
else
    MPI_Allreduce(&dsum, &dsum_total, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, SlaveComm);

return dsum_total;
```

}

I call this function at the three different locations in the same forloop, that means

```
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
   newrho = symmat->Lddot_MPI(n,r,z,false); 
  .
  .
  .
   newrho1 = symmat->Lddot_MPI(n,r,z,false); 
  .
  .
  .
   newrho2 = symmat->Lddot_MPI(n,r,z,false);
  .
  .
  .
 }
```

Since before each time this function is called, MPI_Barrier is used to synchronize all the tasks. (This is added only for testing purpose). So the cpu time calculated is only the cpu time of this function. Since the function is called in forloop repeated, the cpu time is the accumulated cpu time of all the repeated calls. I found that the cpu time of this three functions (or the same function at three locations) are different substantially. One can be 20 times longer than the other. I also write out the cpu time of each call. One function is also be longer than the other consistently.

I think the computation and communication are the same for this function at three locations. I wonder why cpu times are so different. Is it possible the code previous to that function can have effect on that?

Comment: you should move the `MPI_Barrier()` right before `MPI_Allreduce()`. the dot product performance heavily depends on the location of the vectors (main memory or (high level) cache. also, make sure you always measure the time on the same task unless you choose to add yet an other `MPI_Barrier()` right after `MPI_Allreduce()`

Comment: If you are not sure `clock()` is monotonic, you should consider using `MPI_Wtime()` instead. Also, make sure MPI tasks are correctly bound (to cores unless you are using OpenMP). Otherwise your timers might be incorrect.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, Thank you for your answer. What is the purpose of using MPI_Barrier() immediately before MPI_Allreduce()? Is it used to improve the performance or to make the time calculation more accurate?

Comment: Make time calculation more accurate